# Keep getting Connection Reset Error 10054 when scraping Amazon jobs results

Tags: python, web-scraping

Obviously I'm still new to Python by looking at my code but failing my way through it.

I am scraping Amazon jobs search results but keep getting a connection reset error 10054 after about 50 requests to the url. I added a Crawlera proxy network to prevent getting banned but still not working. I know the url is long but it seems to work without having to add too many other separate parts to the url. The results page has about 12,000 jobs total with 10 jobs per page, so I don't even know if scraping that much data is the problem to begin with. Amazon shows each page in the url as 'result_limit=10', so I've been going through each page by 10s instead of 1 page per request. Not sure if that's right. Also, the last page stops at 9,990.

The code works but not sure how to get passed the connection error. As you can see, I've added things like a user agent but not sure if it even does anything. Any help would be appreciated as I've been stuck on this for countless days and hours. Thanks!

```
def get_all_jobs(pages):
requests = 0
start_time = time()
total_runtime = datetime.now()

for page in pages:
    try:
        ua = UserAgent()
        header = {
            'User-Agent': ua.random
        }
        response = get('https://www.amazon.jobs/en/search.json?base_query=&city=&country=USA&county=&'
                       'facets%5B%5D=location&facets%5B%5D=business_category&facets%5B%5D=category&'
                       'facets%5B%5D=schedule_type_id&facets%5B%5D=employee_class&facets%5B%5D=normalized_location'
                       '&facets%5B%5D=job_function_id&job_function_id%5B%5D=job_function_corporate_80rdb4&'
                       'latitude=&loc_group_id=&loc_query=USA&longitude=&'
                       'normalized_location%5B%5D=Seattle%2C+Washington%2C+USA&'
                       'normalized_location%5B%5D=San+Francisco'
                       '%2C+California%2C+USA&normalized_location%5B%5D=Sunnyvale%2C+California%2C+USA&'
                       'normalized_location%5B%5D=Bellevue%2C+Washington%2C+USA&'
                       'normalized_location%5B%5D=East+Palo+Alto%2C+California%2C+USA&'
                       'normalized_location%5B%5D=Santa+Monica%2C+California%2C+USA&offset={}&query_options=&'
                       'radius=24km&region=&result_limit=10&schedule_type_id%5B%5D=Full-Time&'
                       'sort=relevant'.format(page),
                       headers=header,
                       proxies={
                           "http": "http://1ea01axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:@proxy.crawlera.com:8010/"
                       }
                       )
        # Monitor the frequency of requests
        requests += 1

        # Pauses the loop between 8 and 15 seconds
        sleep(randint(8, 15))
        current_time = time()
        elapsed_time = current_time - start_time
        print("Amazon Request:{}; Frequency: {} request/s; Total Run Time: {}".format(requests,
              requests / elapsed_time, datetime.now() - total_runtime))
        clear_output(wait=True)

        # Throw a warning for non-200 status codes
        if response.status_code != 200:
            warn("Request: {}; Status code: {}".format(requests, response.status_code))

        # Break the loop if number of requests is greater than expected
        if requests > 999:
            warn("Number of requests was greater than expected.")
            break

        yield from get_job_infos(response)

    except AttributeError as e:
        print(e)
        continue


def get_job_infos(response):

    amazon_jobs = json.loads(response.text)

    for website in amazon_jobs['jobs']:
        site = website['company_name']
        title = website['title']
        location = website['normalized_location']
        job_link = 'https://www.amazon.jobs' + website['job_path']
        yield site, title, location, job_link


def main():
    # Page range starts from 0 and the middle value increases by 10 each page.
    pages = [str(i) for i in range(0, 9990, 10)]

    with open('amazon_jobs.csv', "w", newline='', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["Website", "Title", "Location", "Job URL"])
        writer.writerows(get_all_jobs(pages))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not expert on amazon anti bot policies, but if they have flagged you once, your ip could be flagged for a while, they might have a limit to how many similar requests you can do in a certain time frame. 
google for a patch to urllib so you can see the request headers in real time, other than ip/domain per certain time frame, amazon will look at your request headers to determine if you're not human. compare what you're sending with a regular browser request headers

just standard practice, keep cookies for a normal amount of time, use proper referers and a popular user agent
all this can be done with requests library, pip install requests, see session object

it looks like you're sending a request to an internal amazon url without a referer header..... that doesnt happen in a normal browser

another example, keeping cookies from one user agent and then switching to another is also not what browser does

Comment: Thank you Edo Edo. I will take your advice and make the changes. There might not be much more I can do than that.